# best way to check variables against long value list

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have 2 list of values I need to compare, to separate variables, before I call a function
so variable `args[0]` needs to be found in the list (orange, apple, banana, grape, strawberry, etc...) and variable `args[1]` needs to be found in the list (bike, car, motorcycle, boat, etc...)

I need to find a good value for both before proceeding to the next step.

I could use a nasty looking if statement such as

```
if ( (args[0] == "orange" || args[0] == "apple"|| and so on) && (args[1]) == "bike" || agrs[1] == "car" || and so on) )
```

but that can get really ugly to work with really fast. Is there a better way to skin the cat?

I don't see any function that I can use  `if ( (args[0] in (apple, orange, etc...) && (args[1] in ...))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var list1 = ['orange', 'apple'];
var list2 = ['bike', 'car'];

if(list1.indexOf(args[0]) > -1 && list2.indexOf(args[1]) > -1){

}
```

Notes:

- This uses strict equality (same as `===`).
- It is case sensitive, so `Orange` will not match `orange`.

Comment: 28.8k points and still farming them?

Comment: What a great comment! Cheers

Comment: This is a duplicate, yet you decided to answer it.